# In Idris, how do I hide something defined in Prelude?

Tags: idris

I want to define my own version of `fib` to play around with, but `fib` is exported by the `Prelude`. How do I hide the import from the `Prelude`? In Haskell I would write `import Prelude hiding (fib)`, but that doesn't work in Idris.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As this Idris mailing [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/idris-lang/fRQxu6EuUgM/nuWQmjL-svAJ) suggests:

> At the minute, all there is the (as yet undocumented) `%hide` directive, which makes a name inaccessible.

Here is an example:

```
%hide fib

fib : Nat -> Nat
fib Z = Z
fib (S Z) = S Z
fib (S (S n)) = fib n + fib (S n)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation on what %hide does?

Comment: No, not really. There is this [syntax guide](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/fb9a5ec0080020b5289a95658920ab9524be39b0/docs/reference/syntax-guide.rst#L470) and this [mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/idris-lang/fRQxu6EuUgM/nuWQmjL-svAJ).

Comment: The syntax guide isn't very helpful - my guess was it was for hiding something I was exporting, not importing...