# How can I hide a name in the REPL?

Tags: import, module, read-eval-print-loop, ambiguous, idris

As stated in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43878995/5044950), the [`%hide` directive](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/v1.0/docs/reference/syntax-guide.rst#directives) allows one to make an existing name inaccessible:

```
import Data.String

%hide fib

%default total

fib : Nat -> Nat
fib n = loop n 0 1
  where
    loop : Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Nat
    loop Z a _ = a
    loop (S k) a b = loop k b (a + b)

parseNat : String -> Maybe Nat
parseNat = map cast . parsePositive

response : String -> String
response s = case parseNat s of
  Just n => "fib n = " ++ show (fib n)
  Nothing => "n ∉ ℕ"

partial main : IO ()
main = repl "n = " ((++ "\n") . response)
```

This works fine in the code above:

```
*Main> :exec
n = 10
fib n = 55
```

However, it does not seem to carry over to the REPL:

```
*Main> fib 10
Can't disambiguate name: Main.fib, Prelude.Nat.fib
```

**How can I cause the `%hide` directives from my code to carry over into the REPL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't and the only way to invoke your function is to use its fully qualified name, e.g. `Main.fib 10` would work.