# Implementing an interface for a plain old recursive data type

Tags: interface, idris, recursive-datastructures

I'm fighting with Idris syntax, it seems.

```
module Test

data Nat = Z | S Nat

Eq Nat where
  Z == Z = True
  S n1 == S n2 = n1 == n2
  _ == _ = False
```

This complains with the following error (v1.1.1):

```
.\.\Test.idr:5:8: error: expected: "@",
    "with", argument expression,
    constraint argument,
    function right hand side,
    implicit function argument,
    with pattern
Eq Nat where
       ^
Type checking .\.\Test.idr
```

I don't understand why, I basically used the same syntax as the docs.

When I write an `Eq` implementation for a custom, non-recursive type, such as `Bool`, it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `S n` patterns in parenthesis. After doing that, your will get compiler errors because `Nat` is already defined in `Prelude`. So to compile your code just replace `Nat` with `Natural` (or anything else). Though, `Z` and `S` constructors are also defined in `Prelude` so you either need to rename everything to be able to test in REPL easily or use [`%hide` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878995/in-idris-how-do-i-hide-something-defined-in-prelude).

But at least this code compiles:

```
module Test

data Natural = Z | S Natural

Eq Natural where
  Z == Z = True
  (S n1) == (S n2) = n1 == n2
  _ == _ = False
```

Comment: Ah, of course, I'd do the same in Haskell. Seems like Idris still has a long way to go in terms of compiler errors :)

Comment: @SebastianGraf Yes, Idris error messages are not so great.. As well as Idris parser, I guess. But things are improving. I hope community of this language will grow big enough and ecosystem will be improved dramatically :)